# DataSet.GetXmlSchema always results in xsd attributes have type='xs:string'

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml

Can anyone help me out with this problem?
I am creating an XML document using the Linq XElement class.
Once the document is created I put it into a dataset object. The dataset allow object allows me to infer the XSD schema from the created XML, which is handy.
But... the datatypes in the XSD all come out as type string, even for numeric values.

Below is some sample code that reproduces the problem:

```
class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }

    public XElement GetXML()
    {
        var person = new XElement("Person", new XAttribute("ID", ID));
        person.Add(new XElement("Name", Name));
        person.Add(new XElement("Age", Age));
        person.Add(new XElement("Score", Score));
        return person;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var set = new DataSet("Test");
    var root = new XElement("root");

    var p1 = new Person() { ID = 1, Name = "P1", Age = 32, Score = 50.4 };
    var p2 = new Person() {ID = 2, Name = "P2", Age = 40, Score = 0 };

    root.Add(p1.GetXML());
    root.Add(p2.GetXML());

    set.ReadXml(root.CreateReader());
    var xml = set.GetXml();
    var schema = set.GetXmlSchema();

    Console.WriteLine(schema);
    Console.WriteLine(xml);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

When you run the code, the schema will contain items like the following:

```
<xs:element name="Age" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
```

I cannot see how I can set the type for this to be integer, for example.

I tried changing the following line:
*set.ReadXml(root.CreateReader());*
to:
*set.ReadXml(root.CreateReader(), XmlReadMode.InferTypedSchema);*
This almost worked but it still did not produce the exact types I want. Also the use resulted in inconsistent values (sometimes values with decimal types such as Score would be type='xs:double', other times they would be type='xs:Anonymous'

Is there any way I can specify the datatype of attributes and nodes?
Note that I am in a position where I must use the Syste.Data.DataSet class to hold the xml in the end, but I do not necessarily have to use the linq XElement class to construct the XML to place in it. I suspect the problem may be related to the XNodeReader object created by calling CreateReader, as well as the simplistic nature of the XElement class.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: When I used `set.ReadXml(root.CreateReader(), XmlReadMode.InferTypedSchema);`, I did notice that it used xs:unsignedByte and xs:decimal. What is the desired schema?

Comment: I'd like to be able to hardcode the types, so that Age always comes out as integer, Score always comes out as decimal, etc.

If when using InterTypedSchema here, it attempts to dynamically determine the type, so if the ID attribute were something like 5000 it would result in the type being unsignedShort. This means the XSD will be different each time depending on the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you generate the XML you lose all the type information - XML contains just strings. You should go directly via a `DataTable` - something like this:

```
class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }

    public DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
      DataTable result = new DataTable();
      result.Columns.Add("ID", ID.GetType());
      result.Columns.Add("Name", Name.GetType());
      result.Columns.Add("Age", Age.GetType());
      result.Columns.Add("Score", ID.GetType());
      return result;
    } 
}

class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var set = new DataSet("Test");

    var p1 = new Person() { ID = 1, Name = "P1", Age = 32, Score = 50.4 };
    set.Tables.Add(p1.GetDataTable());
    var schema = set.GetXmlSchema();

    Console.WriteLine(schema);

  }
}
```